# How can I use Postfix to track/log the HELO name that IPs are communicating to it with

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server

I am using Postfix as an internal mail relay server, and we have several servers internally running all sorts of custom code, some are packages/services, and some of it is native Linux or Windows system services that use this/these systems to communicate as a mail relay.

The problem I'm encountering is that I am working on cleaning up the server HELO names that they are communicating to the server as when sending mail, some are localhost.localdomain for example and it's hurting our IP reputation (blacklists/etc)

I installed pflogsumm which has been a great help, but I really wish there was a way I could get a list of IPs that are connecting to this server and the corresponding HELOs that the IPs are making (or their servernames that they are reporting as if you know what I mean).

If anyone knows how I can get this information from Postfix that would be great, a bonus would be able to expose this to pflogsumm so that I can view it in my daily mail report. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wietse Venema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wietse_Venema) (author of [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/)) gave this [answer](http://readlist.com/lists/postfix.org/postfix-users/30/150306.html) to a [question](http://readlist.com/lists/postfix.org/postfix-users/30/150305.html) asked in 2012 on the `postfix-users` [mailinglist](http://readlist.com/lists/postfix.org/postfix-users/):

```
warn_if_reject check_helo_access static:reject
```

It is probably current, give it a try.

**Update**

I gave it a try:

First of all the configuration needs to be made in the [smtpd_helo_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_helo_restrictions) configuration directive.

```
smtpd_helo_restrictions = warn_if_reject check_helo_access static:reject
```

This will result in log entries of the following sort:

```
Oct 16 00:12:45 vega postfix/smtpd[6676]: NOQUEUE: reject_warning: RCPT from unknown[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::x]: 554 5.7.1 <test>: Helo command rejected: Access denied; from=<anybody@example.com> to=<somebody@example.com> proto=SMTP helo=<test>
```

In this case I used `test` in the `HELO` command of the `SMTP` connection. With this being a reject_warning, `pflogsumm` will have probably no problem summarizing this.

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed response, I'm excited to try it and will report back! Much appreciated and have a great day.

Comment: I got this error `postfix: fatal: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 44: missing '=' after attribute name: "smtpd_helo_restrictions warn_if_reject check_helo_access static:reject"` but it was simple enough to understand that it needed to be `smtpd_helo_restrictions = warn_if_reject check_helo_access static:reject`

Comment: Oh, my bad in copy-paste... I will fix this in my answer!

Comment: No worries! It works pretty much perfectly from what I can tell as far as testing it goes, but there is one small issue related to pflogsumm. When checking the pflogsumm mail statistics report this is what the lines read, it's *almost* right:

    `RCPT`
    `Helo command rejected: Access denied (total: 2)`
           `1   examplehost.domain.local`
           `1   10.10.10.10`

So I tested it with two different hosts, but the problem is that if examplehost.domain.local was something like "localhost.localdomain" in the pflogsumm report it wouldn't correlate to an IP address. If that makes sense

Comment: It makes sense, for a log analyzer there is no need to display the fqdn and the ip address at the same time. You will probably need to adjust the code of pflogsumm for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution presented here results in emails from my mail client (Thunderbird) getting rejected by my own mail server because Thunderbird sends the LAN IP address as HELO host. :(