# How do I get postfix to log the Helo/ehlo responses?

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

I need to get access to the Helo responses in order to make sure everything is set up correctly on the mail server.

Comment: Simply telnet to your smtp port (25) and manually simulate a smtp transaction. The hostname your mailserver responds with is usually the one it will also use when connecting to remote smtp servers. - increasing log verbosity may help too.  See https://serverfault.com/q/729223/960939

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general method of doing this is to increase debug level for [`smtp`](https://www.postfix.org/smtp.8.html) transport. You can add your test peer address into [`debug_peer_list`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#debug_peer_list), and for that peer it will log way more information than usual, including the raw HELO strings it uses when communicating with that peer.

When you assure it works as expected, remove the address from the list. It makes the logging *really verbose*, up to the point it can easily fill your log space.